# Corrupted size vs. prev_size with print function

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that needs to parse numerical ranges such as 80,81,82,10000-13000 etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append_value(int *buffer, int element, size_t *buffer_size) 
{
  printf(".\n");
  buffer[*buffer_size / sizeof(int) - 1] = element;
  *buffer_size += sizeof(int);
  buffer = (int*)realloc(buffer, *buffer_size);

  if (buffer == NULL) {
    printf("error for memory reallocation.\n");
    return;
  }
}
```

```
void parse_portrange(char* strrange, int* buffer, size_t *buffer_size) 
{
  char* save_ptr;
  char ranges[strlen(strrange)];
  strncpy(ranges, strrange, strlen(strrange));

  for (char* token = strtok_r(ranges, ",", &save_ptr); token != NULL; token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &save_ptr))
  {
    if (strchr(token, '-') != NULL) 
    {
      char* save_range_ptr;
      strtok_r(token, "-", &save_range_ptr);

      int from = (int)strtol(token, NULL, 10);
      int to = (int)strtol(save_range_ptr, NULL, 10);

      if (from > to) {
        int temp = from;
        from = to;
        to = temp;
      }

      for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) 
      {
        append_value(buffer, i, buffer_size);
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      int port = (int)strtol(token, NULL, 10);
      append_value(buffer, port, buffer_size);
    }
  }
}
```

```
int main() 
{
  int *portranges = malloc(sizeof(int));
  size_t portranges_size = sizeof(int);
  parse_portrange("25500-25599,80,21", portranges, &portranges_size);

  for (int* i = portranges; i < portranges + portranges_size / sizeof(int); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", *i);
  }
  printf("size: %zu\n", portranges_size);
  free(portranges);
  return 0;
}
```

Oddly enough, the printf(".\n") in append_value is causing the error **corrupted size vs. prev_size**. Yes I could just remove it and it will work but I'm trying to understand why this happens. What is printf doing that I'm unaware of? Is printf even the problem?

Also, the for loop in main prints a random garbage value at the end and displays an extra 4 bytes for the dynamic array size. Why does this happen?

Comment: You have verified that removing that one line "solves" the problem?

Comment: `char ranges[strlen(strrange)];
  strncpy(ranges, strrange, strlen(strrange));` smells. It could be just `memcpy`. `strtok_r(ranges,` is invalid - `ranges` is not zero terminated.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes I have, without the print function the loop in main prints the values correctly.

Comment: @KamilCuk making those changes now, thanks

Comment: `buffer = (int*)realloc` - `buffer` is a local value inside `append_value`. It will not change the value of `portranges` outside it. Function arguments are passed by value. You have to pass a pointer to it like you did with `portranges_size`. I recommend keeping size in count of elements, not size of the memory. `strtok_r(token, "-", &save_range_ptr);` - just `save_range_ptr = strchr(token, '-') + 1`, you used it above in `if`.

Comment: @KamilCuk why not? i passed a pointer to `buffer` in `append_value`. then the returned value of `realloc` is assigned to the value the buffer is pointing to. is their a need for a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: You did not pass a pointer to `buffer`. I see no `&buffer`. You passed `buffer` by value.

Comment: @KamilCuk ah i see, i thought that since buffer is already a pointer, their was no need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code with comments works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// we need to modify buffer, so pass a pointer to it
void append_value(int **buffer, int element, size_t *buffer_size) {
  // first allocate memory, then assign, when new element comes
  // don't cast result of *alloc
  // assign to temporary variable
  void *tmp = realloc(*buffer, *buffer_size * sizeof(int));
  if (tmp == NULL) {
    // print error messages on stderr
    fprintf(stderr, "error for memory reallocation.\n");
    // do not continue the execution after allocation error
    abort();
  }
  *buffer = tmp;
  // add new element
  (*buffer)[*buffer_size] = element;
  *buffer_size += 1;
}

// string literals are immutable - so do const it
void parse_portrange(const char *strrange, int **buffer, size_t *buffer_size) 
{
  char* save_ptr = NULL;
  // + 1 -  zero terminating character
  char ranges[strlen(strrange) + 1];
  // If you know the size of source string, strncpy is just strangr
  memcpy(ranges, strrange, strlen(strrange) + 1);

  for (char* token = strtok_r(ranges, ",", &save_ptr); token != NULL; token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &save_ptr)) {
    if (strchr(token, '-') != NULL) {
      char *save_range_ptr = strchr(token, '-') + 1;

      // superflous casts
      int from = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
      int to = strtol(save_range_ptr, NULL, 10);
      // TODO: handle strtol errors

      if (from > to) {
        int temp = from;
        from = to;
        to = temp;
      }

      for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        append_value(buffer, i, buffer_size);
      }
    } else {
      int port = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
      // TODO handle strtol error
      append_value(buffer, port, buffer_size);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  // initialize with zero elements at the start
  // inside append_value assign new element post-allocating
  int *portranges = NULL;
  // keep the count of elements, not size of array
  size_t portranges_size = 0;
  // pass a pointer to portranges
  parse_portrange("25500-25599,80,21", &portranges, &portranges_size);

  for (int *i = portranges, *end = portranges + portranges_size;
        i < end; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", *i);
  }
  printf("size: %zu\n", portranges_size);
  free(portranges);
  return 0;
}
```